# LDAP Authentication is not working PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, ldap, authentication

I am trying to do an LDAP Authentication but I get stucked. I couldn't figure out how to continue.

I found this piece of code on the internet and edit a bit. The problem is this does not prompts anything. I am not sure if this is working or not. Can someone help me? I am not sure but I guess connect and bind functions work.

Thanks for help

```
<?php
$server = "127.0.0.1";
$basedn = "ou=people,dc=nodomain";
$script = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
if (isset($HTTP_COOKIE_VARS['cookie'])) {
    $cookie = $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS['cookie'];
}
if (isset($cookie)) {
    $username = $cookie['user'];
    $password = ($cookie['token']);
    $fullname = $cookie['fullname'];
    $fqdn = $cookie['fqdn'];
    $dn = "uid=$username, ";
    if (!($connect = ldap_connect($server))) {
        die("Could not connect to LDAP server");
    }

    if (!($bind = ldap_bind($connect, "$dn" . "$basedn", $password))) {
        die("Could not bind to $dn$basedn");
    }
} else {
    if ((isset($_POST['username'])) && (isset($_POST['password']))) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $filter = "(&(|(!(displayname=Administrator*))(!
(displayname=Admin*)))(cn=$username))";
        $dn = "uid=$username, ";
        if (!($connect = ldap_connect($server))) {
            die("Could not connect to LDAP server");
        }

        ldap_set_option($connect, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

        if (!($bind = ldap_bind($connect, "$dn" . "$basedn",
                        $password))) {
            die("Could not bind to $dn --- $connect");
        }
        $sr = ldap_search($connect, $basedn, "$filter");
        $info = ldap_get_entries($connect, $sr);
        $fullname = $info[0]["displayname"][0];
        $fqdn = $info[0]["dn"];
        setcookie("cookie[user]", $username);
        setcookie("cookie[token]", $password);
        setcookie("cookie[fullname]", $fullname);
        setcookie("cookie[fqdn]", $fqdn);
    } else {
?>


        <html>        
            <head>        
                <title>OTP Login</title>        
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">        
                <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">        
                <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">        
            </head>        
            <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">        
                <!--        
                document.onmousedown=click;        
                function click()        
                {        
                    if (event.button==2) {alert('Right-clicking has been        
                        disabled by        
                        the administrator.');}        
                    }        

                    //-->        
            </SCRIPT>        
            <div align="center">        
                <form method="post" action="<? echo $script; ?>">
                    <div align="center">        

                        <table width="210" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">        
                            <tr>        
                                <td align="center">        
                                    <fieldset>        
                                        <Legend><font face="Verdana,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif" size="1"        
                                                      color="gray">Enter Credentials</font></Legend>        
                                        <table border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0">        
                                            <tr>        
                                                <td align="right" valign="middle"><b><font        
                                                            face="Verdana,Tahoma,Arial,sans-        
                                                            serif" size="1" color="gray">Username:</font></td>        
                                                <td align="center" valign="middle">        
                                                    <input class="clear" type="text" size="15" name="username">        
                                                </td>        
                                            </tr>        
                                            <tr>        
                                                <td align="right" valign="middle"><b><font        
                                                            face="Verdana,Tahoma,Arial,sans-        
                                                            serif" size="1" color="gray">Password:</font></td>        
                                                <td align="center" valign="middle">        
                                                    <input class="pass" type="password" size="15"        
                                                           name="password">        
                                                </td>        
                                            </tr>        
                                        </table>        
                                        <input type=image src="images/login.gif" alt="Login"        
                                               name="image">        
                                        <br>        
                                        </div>        
                                        </td>        
                                        </tr>        
                                    </fieldset>        
                        </table>        
                        <br>        
                        <table width="640"><tr><td align="center">        
                                    <font face="Verdana,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif" size="1"        
                                          color="silver">This System is        
                                        for the use of authorized users only. Please enter your username and password as well as your OTP</font>        
                                </td></tr></table>        

                    </div>        
                </form>        

            </div>        
        </body>        
        </html>        
<?
        die ();
    }
}
$>
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing password in a cookie is generally a bad idea and should be removed from your code.

The code:

```
    if (!($connect = ldap_connect($server))) {
        die("Could not connect to LDAP server");
    }

    ldap_set_option($connect, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

    if (!($bind = ldap_bind($connect, "$dn" . "$basedn",
                    $password))) {
        die("Could not bind to $dn --- $connect");
    }
```

is what's doing your authentication, and should be valid. Although dying is a bit harsh if bind fails, as this means authentication was denied. I would rather output some text saying incorrect login.